# Prevent CSV file injection when generated in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am generating a CSV file in Java Spring Boot code. Some data comes from the user, so I need to check the security of CSV from CSV injection.

I found one library which escapes special characters

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>

StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(data);
```

I am not sure if it resolves CSV injection issue as well. Is it secure to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. The `StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv` only changes quotes and newlines. You can check the code of the latest version [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/261a5797bdfc3a5012c1475a69f80a12ab2a84cc/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.java#L253)

To assert the problem of CSV injection, you should:

> [...] ensure that no cells begin with any of the following characters:
>
> Equals to (=)
>
> Plus (+)
>
> Minus (-)
>
> At (@)
>
> Tab (0x09)
>
> Carriage return (0x0D)

As you can see in this OWASP entry: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CSV_Injection